# Acceleration $\mathbf a$ in function of the velocity $\mathbf v$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, physics, solution-verification

In the Physics.SE, I have seen this very nice [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552602/alternative-expression-of-acceleration-in-vector-form/552610#552610) where the acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ is obtained using the differential operator $\boldsymbol \nabla$.

$$\mathbf{a}=\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}=\color{red}{\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial x}+\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial y}+\frac{dz}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial z}=(\mathbf{v}\cdot\boldsymbol \nabla)\:\mathbf{v}}$$

Why can I obtained the expression coloured in red?

Comment: The chain rule.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have thinked the same considering the `partial` symbol as a `d`. But I have not understood with the chain rule. Every answer is welcome. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A particular case of) the multivariable chain rule says:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\big(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t)\big)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{dx_i}{dt}.$$
In your specific case:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}\big(x(t),y(t),z(t)\big)=\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$
Now the result follows from noting that $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}$ is equal to:
$$(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}=\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{dz}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\mathbf{v}.$$

Comment: Thank you very very much for your clear explanation.